# Vectors in myclass. error: parenthesized initializer in array new [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, class, stdvector

I'm new to C++

```
class BlenderMesh{
public:
    std::vector<double[3]>          vertex_vectors;
    std::vector<double[3]>          normal_vectors;
    std::vector<double[2]>          uv_vectors;
    std::vector<std::string>        texture_list;
    std::vector<int[6]>             face_indices;
    std::vector<int[3]>             normal_indices;
    std::vector<int[3]>             uv_indices;
                                    BlenderMesh();
                                    ~BlenderMesh();};
```

Error in code: mesh->vertex_vectors.push_back(vertex);

```
BlenderMesh::BlenderMesh(){}

BlenderMesh::~BlenderMesh(){}

BlenderMesh* mesh = new BlenderMesh();

PyObject* vertexVectors = PyList_GetItem(blenderObject,2);
unsigned int size_vertex_vectors = PyObject_Size(vertexVectors);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size_vertex_vectors; i++){
    double vertex[3];
    PyObject* pyVertex = PyList_GetItem(vertexVectors,i);
    PyObject* vertexX = PyTuple_GetItem(pyVertex,0);
    vertex[0] = PyFloat_AsDouble(vertexX);
    PyObject* vertexY = PyTuple_GetItem(pyVertex,1);
    vertex[1] = PyFloat_AsDouble(vertexY);
    PyObject* vertexZ = PyTuple_GetItem(pyVertex,2);
    vertex[2] = PyFloat_AsDouble(vertexZ);
    mesh->vertex_vectors.push_back(vertex);
    }
```

Console:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: parenthesized initializer in array new [-fpermissive]
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }


/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/ext/new_allocator.h:124:29: error: request for member '~double [3]' in '* __p', which is of non-class type 'double [3]'
         destroy(_Up* __p) { __p->~_Up(); }
```

Comment: What happens when you do `push_back` is essentially an assignment. You can't assign arrays only copy them. Instead I suggest you use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of plain C arrays.

Comment: A vector of arrays? Why? Did you mean a vector of `double` that has 3 elements in it? Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: Thanks!  I learned how to write correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Well it has been four years but hopefully this helps someone. For some reason you are not able to create a vector object containing a native list of objects (maybe someone could explain why?).

So, for example, when creating a 18x2 vector containing 1'ns for example:

```
std::vector<double[2]> my_vector(18, {1.0, 1.0});
```

So instead you should to the following:

```
std::vector<vector<double>> my_vector(18, vector<double>(2,{1.0, 1.0});
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, a std::array can be used:

```
std::vector<std::array<double,2>> my_vector(18, std::array<double,2>{1.0, 1.0});
```